# r - merge rows in group while replacing NAs

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, row, na

I was trying to find the answer to this but couldn't. If there is an answer I apologize and will immediately delete my question.

I'm trying to merge several rows into one (this calculation should be done separately on groups, in this case variable `id` can be used to group), so that no NA values are left.

```
# initial dataframe
df_start <- data.frame(
  id = c("as", "as", "as", "as", "as", "bs", "bs", "bs", "bs", "bs"), 
  b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, 6, NA, NA), 
  c = c(2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
  d = c(NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, NA), 
  e = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, "B", NA), 
  f = c(NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10))

# desired output
df_end <- data.frame(id = c("as", "bs"), 
                     b = c("A", 6), 
                     c = c(2, 7), 
                     d = c(4, 8), 
                     e = c(3,"B"), 
                     f = c(5, 10))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to delete the question, it may be helpful to some users. This summarises each group to the first non NA occurrence for each column.

```
library(dplyr)

df_start <- data.frame(
  id = c("as", "as", "as", "as", "as", "bs", "bs", "bs", "bs", "bs"), 
  b = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, 6, NA, NA), 
  c = c(2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
  d = c(NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, NA), 
  e = c(NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, "B", NA), 
  f = c(NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10))

df_start %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise_all(list(~first(na.omit(.))))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  id    b         c     d e         f
  <fct> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <dbl>
1 as    A        2.    4. 3        5.
2 bs    6        7.    8. B       10.
```

You will, of course, get some data lost if there is more than one occurrence of a value with each group for each column.

Comment: What is this now that `funs` is deprecated?

Comment: @BrianWiley use `list` https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html

Comment: Thanks I got it to work with a lambda.  I just don't think mine is finishing due to memory because its a dataframe that is 900k rows and 214 variables with 514k groups.  I used dplyr full joins and removed duplicate columns instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps, Using dplyr

```
df_start <- sapply(df_start, as.character)
df_start[is.na(df_start)] <- " "
df_start <- as.data.frame(df_start)

library(dplyr)   
df_start %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(trimws(paste(., collapse = '')))) -> df
```